# Is it possible to have CSS rounded corners on an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've looked around, and as far as I can see it's not possible, but say you're embedding a YouTube iframe, is it possible to round those corners using CSS?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The div container method described in [How to Get Rounded Corners on an iFrame using Border-Radius CSS](https://web.archive.org/web/20140822054815/http://trycode.co.za/css-tricks/how-to-get-rounded-corners-on-an-iframe-using-border-radius-css/) works for me.

> And to do this you simply wrap the iFrame in div tags and give the div these css properties:
>
> `<div style="border-radius: 10px; width: 300px; overflow: hidden;">`
>
> The `border-radius` should be set to whatever you want the roundness to be, and the `width` must be set to the width of the iFrame, else you will get only a few (if any) rounded corners. But the most important thing is the **overflow: hidden**, as this hides the iFrames real corners.

Comment: @Ryan In Chrome you can just apply `border-radius: 10px` directly to the iframe.

Comment: @feklee as of the current version (28.0.1500.95) an iframe scroll bar will still remain square and will not be rounded.  Wrapping it in a div with overflow hidden doesn't work either.  The scroll bar will appear to overflow the container.  Firefox and IE work fine.

Answer (score 3):

The way to go is wrapping the iframe in a circular div as other users suggested. The only difference being that you have to add an additional style `position:relative` to the wrapper for it to work in Chrome browser.

So the code would go like this:

```css
.circle {
 width: 320px;
 height: 320px;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_8CP1tT8tdk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the `<iframe>` in a `<div>` should work.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
iframe {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <iframe src="http://google.com" />
</div>
```

I have attached a jsfiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/fxPsC/

Comment: Thanks, almost what I was wanting, but I rather wanted the actual iframe to have rounded corners - no borders.  It doesn't seem possible.

Comment: SimonRentzke is right. I even tried with `overflow:hidden`, but it clips to a square.

Comment: You may want to also include `border-radius:10px`, without the "-moz" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add it to the iframe tag if your tag has inline style:

```
    <iframe 
    width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"
    frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0;border-radius: 25px\";
    src=". $locationlink ." allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
iframe {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```