# Perfect Responsive Circle iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design, geometry

How would I create an iFrame that is a perfect circle and responsive? [I know I can add rounded corners by surrounding the iframe with a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738985/is-it-possible-to-have-css-rounded-corners-on-an-iframe/12424164#12424164), but I'm not sure how I can make a perfect circle.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your `iframe` with two divs. The inner one should be `position: absolute;`, while the outer one should be `position: relative`. You can use a static and equal height and width in order to make it a perfect circle, [**as shown in this jsfiddle examples**](http://jsfiddle.net/fb7nb90w/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="iframe-outer"><!--position: relative-->
    <div class="iframe-inner"><!--position: absolute-->
        <iframe src="www.google.com" width="600" height="450"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, because we live in a world of varying screen sizes, and because you want a *perfect circle*, it's useful to add a little more CSS to allow for this to be responsive, [based on Nathan Ryan's answer to "Height Equal To Dynamic Width."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout)

[Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate a complete solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/jy1yjmmL/2/)

Comment: I'm schizophrenic.  And so am I.  Haha, nice.