# How to put div over the object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

In a htm file(IE), I use the "object" to include a plugin written in Visual Studio, the plugin is used to show video from a camera.

Now there is a need to put a div over the object,but I find that the div is always below the video and z-index does not work.I searched the Internet and find that "object" is a windowed element in IE, and all the windowed element will be shown over the windowless element.

What I find is all like this and there is no solutions to put div over the object : [How to cover an IE windowed control (Select Box, ActiveX Object, etc.) with a DHTML layer?](http://www.macridesweb.com/oltest/IframeShim.html).

It seem that the only way to put div over the object is to use iframe(but i'am not sure), put ifame over the object and put div over the iframe,but if the div has a round corner,the color in the corner of the iframe is the color of the whole page instead of the video,that confused me a lot. I have searched for the solution for many days but no result.

what I want to solve is below:

1. Without using iframe, can I put the div over the object(Windowed element)?
2. While using iframe, can I make the color in the corner of the iframe be the color of the video?

Comment: Did you try just positioning the element and placing it where you want it, something like `position:absolute; top:-200px` etc.

Comment: I just want to put div above the object, I have tried what you say but it does not work. Thank you all the same.

Comment: `I find is all like this and there is no solutions to put div over the object` - so, you've done some research, found something that says it can't be done, but ask `can I put the div above the object` - either you don't trust your research or you think you'll find a magician on SO :) ... the problem is IE, it's demise is overdue

Comment: iFrame with round corners: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12424164/6307292

Comment: @Jaromanda X I just mean I can not find the solution and what I mean is not there is no solution, sorry for my bad words. Thank you for pointing out my fault.

Comment: @mm759 Sadly, If surround the iframe with div, the iframe will be below the video again.In this occasion,z-index does not work.